# Custom Certificate Authority not recognised on Windows server / Cert shows as "self signed"

Tags: ssl, certificate-authority

Scenario:
We run our own Certificate Authority for internal server to server TLS connections. Created a new SSL certificate for a web server. Deployed to server, SSL works....

Send CA public key and certificate public key to "client" machine (another Windows server), import certs into registry.

In theory I should be able to open the webserver via https without error.

However I get "Invalid cert, self signed" (paraphrased) with each way I tried: Firefox, IE, Postman.

### The error messages in detail:

- Firefox: ...uses an invalid security certificate MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT
- IE: The security certificate presented by this website was not issued by a trusted certificate authority.

[image: Valid CA]

What do I miss?

Comment: Which location did it get added to in your certificate store?  Open up the certificates mmc, or look in powershell under the `cert:\` drive.

Comment: @garethTheRed That really ought to be an answer, not a comment!

Answer (score 2):

Self-signed certificates are only trusted if they are marked as such; otherwise they are un-trusted and provide no real worth.  Browsers (and applications) generally show an error when they are presented with such certificates, which is what you're seeing.

The self-signed certificate should be in Windows's **Trusted Root Certification Authority** store for Internet Explorer (and Chrome) to recognise it as a Root CA.

Firefox uses it's own trust-store, therefore the self-signed certificate  needs to be added.  From **Options** > **Privacy and Security** > **View Certificates**, select the **Authorities** tab and add the certificate. Click **Edit Trust...** and select **This certificate can identify websites**.